Having problem sending ETH from contract to MetaMask wallet using Remix
im trying to figure out how the contract works so i created and deployed one contract using Remix having "withdraw" function which is supposed to send 0.001ETH from contract to my MetaMask wallet but im only seeing gas price and no actual ETH value in my wallet and the balance is not getting up as well. It's getting more confusing for me as in transaction details (https://etherscan.io/tx/0x7c6dd282a2ae9f189be4fa57103bd683e98845035591a5659f1c3e415636ff9d) i can see the 0.001ETH was sent but never received by the wallet.
This is the code, im using hardcoded value 0.001ETH and metaMaskWallet is my wallet address:
       function withdrawTestFunds() external onlyOwner {
        uint balance = address(this).balance;
        require(balance > 0, "No Ether to withdraw");
        require(balance >= 0.001 ether, "Insufficient balance to withdraw 0.001 Ether");

        uint amountToWithdraw = 0.001 ether; // Fixed withdrawal amount
        payable(metaMaskWallet).transfer(amountToWithdraw);
        emit Withdrawal(metaMaskWallet, amountToWithdraw);
    }


As you can see in the transaction state, 0.001 ETH was received by the address 0x6683973bBFC9a98722bfc61e2A311FA3B6648812 as the balance of this address increased by 0.00047851449732055 ETH = 0.001 ETH (amount sent by the contract) - 0.00052148550267945 ETH (tx fee).
What do you mean by "im only seeing gas price and no actual ETH value in my wallet"?

for example here: [https://ibb.co/album/Ypz2HH]  and here [https://ibb.co/album/Ypz2HH]
I'm not seeing any indicator that I received anything in my wallet and my wallet balance was also same in dollars.
Same happened here; when i tried to withdrawal amount it went to 0 ETH and i didnt receive anything in my account.
https://etherscan.io/address/0xEa1273eeCd77973795Fb283900FF3fF55Cb14860

Could you please upload the pics again? They've expired I guess.
